# Install openssh-server package from preseed file

Tags: server, preseed, custom-installer

So I've managed to create a custom ISO using a preseed file that isntalls the OS automatically, all works fine BUT the isntallation of the openssh-server package...I'm not what else to do.

On my preseed file I have the following lines:

```
#Add package
d-i pkgsel/include string openssh-server build-essential
```

however when I login,the package has not been installed. I also need to enable to login with root, for other purpuses so I need to modify the sshd_config file, I have tried the following two options also but I guess they don't work because the openssh-server package doesnt install on the first place:

```
ubiquity ubiquity/success_command string sed -i '/PermitRootLogin/c\PermitRootLogin yes' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

and

```
d-i preseed/late_command string sed -i '/PermitRootLogin/c\PermitRootLogin yes' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

What is the best way to first, add the ssh server package? and then modify the sshd_config file? so when the OS boots the ssh service is started and running

Answer (score 0):

We used and tested the following approach together with the netboot image of Ubuntu.

```
d-i passwd/root-login boolean true
d-i passwd/root-password-crypted password <password>
d-i passwd/make-user boolean false
d-i pkgsel/include string openssh-server
d-i preseed/late_command string \
  in-target sh -c 'sed -i "s/^#PermitRootLogin.*\$/PermitRootLogin yes/g" /etc/ssh/sshd_config';
```

Use the following command to generate the password:

```
printf "please-change-password" | mkpasswd -s -m sha-512
```

[Here](https://github.com/core-process/linux-unattended-installation) you will find a more sophisticated approach using ssh public keys as default. It still contains all the hints in the [preseed](https://github.com/core-process/linux-unattended-installation/blob/master/ubuntu/17.04/custom/preseed.cfg) file regarding password login.

Comment: Can you please explain where I need to put this? I have to login to my headless machine in order to install ubuntu and I believe this is the way I need to go. I just don't understand what file I need to modify in order to do this. Can you please give me instructions?

Comment: You need to add this in preseed.cfg