# How to install openssh-server during the install process

Tags: system-installation

I've successfully executed a fully automated install of Ubuntu 20.04 using the official documentation (https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/amd64/apbs04.html), and simply modifying /grub/grub.cfg and /preseed.ubuntu.seed. The documentation (and example file) suggests using the line

```
d-i pkgsel/include string openssh-server build-essential
```

in the preseed file, but this does not install openssh-server, and furthermore

```
cat /var/log/installer/* | grep openssh
```

returns nothing. I also tried using

```
d-i preseed/late_command string in-target apt install openssh-server
```

but this had no effect either.

**What do I need to include in my preseed file to convince debian-installer (or ubiquity, but as I understand it this is basically a front-end) to actually install openssh-server during the install process?**

Furthermore, I would expect that if I included lines in a preseed file that were not valid or if the installer attempted to install openssh-server and failed, *at the very least* the installer would log an error. Where might I find such a log?

[Here is a similar question from 2017](https://askubuntu.com/questions/935565/install-openssh-server-package-from-preseed-file), but the only answer suggests enabling root--I won't be doing that, and I refuse to believe that's the only possible way.

Comment: What is the result of yhe following command line? `sudo systemctl status sshd.service` If you could add the output to your question it would help a lot.

Comment: Did you read https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbiquityAutomation?