# How to install extra packages when using preseed with 20.04?

Tags: package-management, system-installation, preseed

Copy of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1317770/how-to-install-openssh-server-during-the-install-process) since I'm not allowed to comment on it.

And, just like in the copied question, I'm trying this on 20.04.

How to install extra packages, and I as well would like to install openssh-server (and some more) but neither

`d-i pkgsel/include string openssh-server`

nor

`d-i preseed/late_command string in-target apt-install openssh-server`

nor

`ubiquity ubiquity/success_command string in-target apt-install openssh-server`

installs it

So, how are one supposed to do to get extra packages installed by preseed?

If the problem is Ubiquity - then how can I use debian-installer instead of Ubiquity?
Is it possible to install Desktop Ubuntu without running the graphical installer?

And finally: to answer the question posted in the comment to the linked question:
[Screenshot to show answer to comment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRCKX.png)

Comment: You choose your installer by using an ISO that uses it. Ubuntu has ISOs that use *di* (debian-installer; usually older ISOs), `ubiquity`, `subiquity`, `calamares` and more (the replacement for `ubiquity` is available in a *canary* build).  Yes it's possible to install a desktop system without `ubiquity` for some releases/flavors by using specific ISOs if available for your intended but *unstated* release.

Comment: It's for 20.04 - but that's the answer to a follow-up in case the answer to the main question would somehow necessitate that - I'm more interested in the main part of the question.

Comment: So, the solution ended up being to use the Server ISO and [cloud-init][1] and [this script][2], following [this][3] article.


  [1]: https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/
  [2]: https://github.com/covertsh/ubuntu-autoinstall-generator
  [3]: https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/hpc/How-To-Make-Ubuntu-Autoinstall-ISO-with-Cloud-init-2213/